# Unable to find the file 'spl.jar' for the Stanford C++ Library

Tags: java, c++, qt, jar

I want to do the CS106b/CS106x course of Stanford but have problems running a C++ sample project in Qt successfully. So far it is possible for me to build the project but when I try to run it, the following error message is always shown:

```
***
*** STANFORD C++ LIBRARY ERROR:
*** Unable to find the file 'spl.jar' for the Stanford
*** C++ library's Java back-end process.
*** Please make sure that spl.jar is properly attached to your project.
*** If you are trying to run a stand-alone executable, place spl.jar
*** in the same directory as your executable, or set the system
*** environment variable SPL_HOME to a directory path containing spl.jar.
***
*** (I looked for it in the following directory:)
*** /
***
```

In fact the file 'spl.jar' is in the folder. As you can see from the screenshot.

[image]

Therefore I am assuming that, my computer is just not able to find it or also doesn't have the correct path to it, at least how I understand the last three lines in the error message?! (only a "/")

How can I set the path correctly? Does it have something to do that Java is maybe not correctly installed? I actually should have installed the latest version of Java 8 JDK.

Do you have any other ideas how to solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I found a solution together with a friend. The problem was that my system environment variable SPL_HOME was empty, like already assumed from the error description.

In my case I first checked again if it's empty in the terminal with:

```
launchctl getenv SPL_HOME
```

and then assigned with this a value:

```
launchctl setenv SPL_HOME 'path'
```

'path' was here the direction to the folder where the file spl.jar was in. 
Credits go to this website, which basically describes it very well how to give the variable a value: https://www.schrodinger.com/kb/1842

I hope this solution helps somebody saving time of their lifes.

Edit: Oh you also wanna restart Qt and delete the build / user file of the project and then rebuild + run it.